# Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter App not available in the Windows Store for some odd reason

Tags: windows-8.1, display, tv, mirroring, miracast

I know it is available because it is listed in the Microsoft website..
But the store is not showing it...
Can anyone provide useful input regarding this issue?
Im on Windows 8.1, its an old laptop,
it is **able** to display videos wirelessly by right clicking a video file and clicking Play To,
However I am unable to do full screen mirroring wirelessly..
I think this app will help me..

Comment: 1. It may not be compatible with Windows 8.1, or with your particular build of Windows 8.1; MS has only limited support for that OS.  2. It may not be compatible with your hardware. You'll need to provide more information about the laptop and its wireless card before anyone can offer you any assistance that's more than wild guesses.

Comment: The requirements for the application are the following: “Windows 10 version 17134.0 or higher, Xbox One, Windows 10 version 17134.0 or higher, Windows 8.1”;  it’s certainly on the store itself [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-wireless-display-adapter/9wzdncrfjbb1?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab)

Comment: The Microsoft Wireless Display Adaptor App is for use with a [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/d/microsoft-wireless-display-adapter/8vwdj9bd9xlz) in order to [perform firmware updates for that device](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-the-microsoft-wireless-display-adapter-c66e1bf6-19ca-f4f7-52f6-221fa184b7eb). Do you have one of these devices?

Comment: @Mokubai Wait....I think I got confused.. you are saying that this is for an exteernal adapter that I can buy and not for the one inside the laptop?

Comment: Yes. Almost all laptops with up to date Intel graphics and a compatible Wifi chipset (capable of Wifi Direct) can "project" their display to a compatible Miracast receiver without that application. I've done it before. But that application is for a specific device manufactured by Microsoft. The device from Microsoft is to turn a "dumb" HDMI only display into one that can receive a projected display.

Comment: To "project" to a wireless display such as a TV press Win+P to bring up the display sidebar, then there should be an option at the bottom "Connect to a wireless display" which will search for displays on your network that are capable of receiving your laptop display wirelessly.

Comment: It just cannot not "Detect" my TV.. It is a Samsung, a newer model I think It came out just over a year ago.. Maybe its Samsung's fault for not providing a wide range of compatibility like my old laptop components? BTW. My drivers are fully updated too